# full_join adding extra rows and NA in r

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I have two data frames that I am trying to join using full_join, here is a subset of my data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Team = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 2L, 1L, 26L, 27L), .Label = c("76ers", 
"76ers ", "Bucks", "Bucks ", "Bull ", "Bulls ", "Cavaliers ", 
"Celtics ", "Clippers ", "Grizzlies ", "Hawks ", "Heat ", "Hornets", 
"Hornets ", "Jazz ", "Kings ", "Knicks ", "Lakers ", "Magic ", 
"Mavericks ", "Net ", "Nets ", "Nuggets ", "Pacers ", "Pelicans ", 
"Pistons", "Pistons ", "Raptors ", "Rockets ", "Spurs ", "Thunder ", 
"Timberwolves ", "Warriors ", "Wizards "), class = "factor"), 
    Injury.Count = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    1L), HomevsAway = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 27L), .Label = c("76ers", 
"Bucks", "Bulls", "Cavaliers", "Celtics", "Clippers", "Grizzlies", 
"Hawks", "Heat", "Hornets", "Jazz", "Kings", "Knicks", "Lakers", 
"Magic", "Mavericks", "Nets", "Nuggets", "Pacers", "Pelicans", 
"Pistons", "Raptors", "Rockets", "Spurs", "Thunder", "Timberwolves", 
"Warriors", "Wizards"), class = "factor"), HomevsAway = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    t_1 = c(55.883, 140.1, 32.2, 37.967, 29.85, 24.317, 57.316, 
    17.967, 19.05, 36.95, 16.167, 95.317, 86.533, 21.334, 52.567, 
    40.75, 28.3, 68.15, 97.067, 102.233, 26.866, 71.033, 34.467, 
    24.233, 42.033, 22.433, 59.033, 41.516, 12.7, 107.996, 6.5, 
    32.783, 0, 23.217, 13.93, 0, 54.88, 23.617, 83.834, 106.794, 
    17.56, 27.76, 85.83, 0.017, 35.183, 22.467, 25.033, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), t_3 = c(197.3164, 388.6827, 126.2663, 
    111.916, 61.95, 91.55, 167.067, 104.083, 71.067, 135.383, 
    45.633, 261.317, 267.399, 114.6997, 159.2, 152.034, 84.8337, 
    204.3003, 351.449, 376.317, 86.333, 213.9, 99.767, 65.1, 
    131.767, 73.317, 126.416, 129.066, 73.383, 347.0994, 4761, 
    113.367, 0, 89.933, 59.8, 0, 188.983, 124.384, 215.666, 289.9667, 
    92, 144.2497, 254.083, 32.0333, 122.1837, 102.533, 82.817, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -56L), groups = structure(list(
    Team = structure(1:28, .Label = c("76ers", "Bucks", "Bulls", 
    "Cavaliers", "Celtics", "Clippers", "Grizzlies", "Hawks", 
    "Heat", "Hornets", "Jazz", "Kings", "Knicks", "Lakers", "Magic", 
    "Mavericks", "Nets", "Nuggets", "Pacers", "Pelicans", "Pistons", 
    "Raptors", "Rockets", "Spurs", "Thunder", "Timberwolves", 
    "Warriors", "Wizards"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3:4, c(5L, 48L), 6:7, c(8L, 49L), c(9L, 50L), c(10L, 
        51L), c(11L, 52L), 12:13, 14:15, c(16L, 53L), 17:18, 
        19:20, c(21L, 54L), 22:23, 24:25, c(26L, 55L), 27:28, 
        29:30, 31:32, 33:34, 35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 41:42, 43:44, 
        c(45L, 56L), 46:47), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 28L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried to join the data using full_join:

```
LR <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("HomevsAway", "Team"))
```

The output of LR I am receiving is giving me extra rows with random NA's involved. My expected output should be a 56rowx5col table.

Comment: @Cettt Any idea on why this is happening on my actual data?

Comment: @Cettt is there a function that I can copy/paste data from R into stackoverflow?

Comment: `dput`. Use `dput(mydata)` and post the result inside the question.

Comment: @Cettt let me know if that works, updated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your first data.frame the Team names have a trailing space. This means that instead of the string `"Bucks"` you have the string `"Bucks "`.
These two strings cannot be joined.

Here is how you can fix your data. First delete leading spaces using `sub` and then transform the Team into a character vector. Then the full_join works as planned:

```
df1_new <- df1 %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(Team = sub(" +", "", as.character(Team)))
df2_new <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Team = as.character(Team))

df1_new %>% full_join(df2_new, by = c("Team", "HomevsAway"))

# A tibble: 58 x 5
   Team      Injury.Count HomevsAway   t_1   t_3
   <chr>            <int> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Bucks                3 0           32.2 126. 
 2 Bucks                3 1           38.0 112. 
 3 Bull                 1 0           NA    NA  
 4 Bulls                1 1            0     0  
 5 Cavaliers            1 0           24.3  91.6
 6 Cavaliers            2 1           57.3 167. 
 7 Celtics              0 0            0     0  
 8 Celtics              2 1           18.0 104. 
 9 Clippers             1 0            0     0  
10 Clippers             1 1           19.0  71.1
```

Note that there are still a few NAs. This is due to some typos: Bull vs Bulls and Net vs Nets.